# How to send a file with XMLHttpRequest with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, xmlhttprequest, cgi

**My html code:**

```
<input type="file" id="attachFileId"" name="contactUs_attach" />
```

**My java script code:**

```
var userfile=document.getElementById('attachFileId').files[0];
var attchment = new FormData();
attchment.append("userfile",userfile);
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST','/cgi-bin/upload.cgi');
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data");
xhr.onload = function() {
  if(xhr.responseText==="y") {
    alert("sucess!");
  }
};
xhr.send(attchment);
```

The above code doesn't work for me. Can someone help to solve this issue?

Comment: where do you call that? Show full code context. If you run it without being in an event handler it will run before user selects files. What errors are thrown? Need more detail than "doesn't work" which is a virtually meaningless technical problem statement. Also take a few minutes to go through [mcve]

Comment: What am I looking at? when you are uploading a file?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. @charlietfl is right, you need to help us by providing the context, and showing what you have done to try and fix it.

Comment: Formatting code

Comment: I was trying to send a file which the user select, from the html page to the server. But the above code doesn't work. It doesn't show any error in the javascript as well as in CGI. When i removed the line xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data"); the code worked and i was able to send the file to the server.

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line:

> ```
> xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',"multipart/form-data");
> ```

A multipart form-data header has to specify the boundary marker in the content, and you can't do that because you aren't generating the boundaries yourself (`FormData` and `XHR` are doing that).

By not specifying the header yourself, you let XHR generate it for you based on the `FormData` object.